# Expose chrome remote-debugging from inside docker container

Tags: docker, chrome-debugging, chrome-remote-debugging

Issue is that chrome binds its debug endpoint to `127.0.0.1` so it looks something like this `ws://127.0.0.1:61552/devtools/browser/30b71668-f77f-4e94-ab53-9514f7bee455`

I have tried using `--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0` flag, but it doesn't seem to change the host.

Docker won't expose any ports connected to 127.0.0.1.
There was a similar problem answered here, that tried to add some kind of reverse proxy, but it didn't work at all, could the websocket be an issue?

Anyone has a solution for this?